# Problems setting up Activity Recognition [Android]

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-recognition

I want to use Activity Recognition API provided by google play services but I have problems in doing so.
First I'm not able to find and updated guide that works for me so I made something similar to the "official" example on github witch is working on my phone.

What I have done so far is that:

1)Added inside the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
```

2)Added inside gradle (It's 10.0.1 beacause I was using other play services with this version)

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
```

3)I created a new class

```
public class ActivityRecognizationIntentService extends IntentService {

public ActivityRecognizationIntentService() {
    super("ActivityRecognizationIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
    Intent localIntent = new Intent(AddictionFour.BROADCAST_ACTION);

    // Get the list of the probable activities associated with the current state of the
    // device. Each activity is associated with a confidence level, which is an int between
    // 0 and 100.
    ArrayList<DetectedActivity> detectedActivities = (ArrayList) result.getProbableActivities();

    // Broadcast the list of detected activities.
    localIntent.putExtra(AddictionFour.ACTIVITY_EXTRA, detectedActivities);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(localIntent);
}}
```

4)Inside the class GameActivity which is where I want to use the API I made this changes (NOTE: I'm posting only code that is relevant)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // connection to Google Play Games
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.getContextOfApplication())
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
    .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
    // add other APIs and scopes here as needed
    .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, 0, getActivityDetectionPendingIntent());
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(AddictionFour.BROADCAST_ACTION));
    super.onResume();
}

private PendingIntent getActivityDetectionPendingIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityRecognizationIntentService.class);

    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when calling
    // requestActivityUpdates() and removeActivityUpdates().
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

public class ActivityDetectionBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //not relevant code for now (read below)
    }

}
```

Basically I'm doing the same things the example on github is doing, app hasn't any error and doesn't crash but onHandleIntent is never called. What am I missing?

PS: all the code inside point 4 is executed except onReceive of ActivityDetectionBroadcastReceiver.

Comment: I tried executing your code and the only issue I had was that I forgot to declare the service in the manifest. Did you declare it?

Comment: @Gonzalo You are right I didn't, now it working but as soon as onReceive is called it crashes but I think now I can handle it. Much thanks!